# Add reference in a section title

Tags: hyperref, section-titles

I'd like to add a reference in my section title like this:

```
\section{Preuve du Théorème \hyperref[theorem:5]{5}}
```

but it doesn't work, I tried to protect my ref but still doesn't work.

Comment: normally it would be enough to use `\ref{theorem:5}` hyperref will make that a link. (it's not usually a good idea to use numbers in reference `\label` , `theorem:5` will reference that theorem and work but be confusing when after editing you look at the source and the internal label is still `theorem:5` but the printed number is 7 or whatever it is .  If you hav ecode that does not work provide a small test docuemnt and say exactly what  error you got.

Comment: Thank you very much \ref{theorem:5} works !!

Answer (score 1):

Normally it would be enough to use `\ref{theorem:5}` hyperref will make that a link.

(it's not usually a good idea to use numbers in reference `\label` , `theorem:5` will reference that theorem and work but be confusing when after editing you look at the source and the internal label is still `theorem:5` but the printed number is 7 or whatever it is.)